# Insertar datos con Stock Procedure Visual estudio. No logro hacer que funcione

Tags: c#

Buenas aquí les dejo el código a ver si me pueden dar una mano.
Estoy intentando insertar datos db con un stock procedure a través de un formulario.
No inserte los registros y tampoco me da ningún error.
Probé incluso poner un nombre incorrecto del SP y tampoco tira erros.
Son 2 formas diferentes las que estaba probando, la primera esta activa y la otra no.

```
            '''Conexion.ConectaDB();
            SqlCommand SP_ALTA_PACIENTE = new SqlCommand("ALTA_PACIENTE",Conexion.ConectaDB());
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            string vdni = txt_dni.Text.Trim();
            string vnombre = txt_nombre.Text.Trim();
            string vapellido = txt_apellido.Text.Trim();
            string vfechanac = date_fechanac.Text.Trim();
            string vdomicilio = txt_domicilio.Text.Trim();
            string vidpais = Convert.ToString(cBoxPais.SelectedValue);
            string vtelefono = txt_telefono.Text.Trim();
            string vemail = txt_email.Text.Trim();
            string vobs = txt_obs.Text.Trim();
            int vidobrasocial = Convert.ToInt32(cBox_ObraSocial.SelectedValue);
            string vnumobra = txt_numobra.Text.Trim();

            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dni",vdni);
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre",vnombre);
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellido",vapellido);
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fnacimiento",vfechanac);
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@domicilio",vdomicilio);
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idpais",vidpais);
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefono",vtelefono);
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",vemail);
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@observacion",vobs);
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idobrasocial",vidobrasocial);
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numobrasocial",vnumobra);
           
            ****** 2 *******
            
            Conexion.ConectaDB();
            SqlDataAdapter SP_ALTA_PACIENTE = new SqlDataAdapter("[CentroMedico].[dbo].[ALTA_PACIENTE]", Conexion.ConectaDB());
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            

            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@dni", SqlDbType.VarChar, (20)).Value = vdni;
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar, (50)).Value = vnombre;
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@apellido", SqlDbType.VarChar, (50)).Value = vapellido;
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@fnacimiento", SqlDbType.VarChar, (8)).Value = vfechanac;
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@domicilio", SqlDbType.VarChar, (50)).Value = vdomicilio;
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@idpais", SqlDbType.VarChar, (3)).Value = vidpais;
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@telefono", SqlDbType.VarChar, (20)).Value = vtelefono;
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, (30)).Value = vemail;//
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@observacion", SqlDbType.VarChar, (1000)).Value = vobs;
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@idobrasocial", SqlDbType.Int).Value = vidobrasocial;
            SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@numobrasocial", SqlDbType.VarChar, (20)).Value = vnumobra;'''
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! como nota, es store procedure... y como te dijeron en la respuesta (que espero que aceptes), estas haciendo todo bien, salvo que nunca ejecutas el comando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para insertar en la base de datos solo te faltaría colocar al final de la instrucción el `ExecuteNonQuery();` para poder insertar.
Y quedaría así:

```
SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idobrasocial",vidobrasocial);
SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numobrasocial",vnumobra);
SP_ALTA_PACIENTE.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Sin eso no le estas diciendo que hacer y solo te lee los parámetros pero no te los insertas.

Comment: La respuesta quedaría mucho mas completa si le das un ejemplo a OP de donde agregar el código y también le explicas cómo tu propuesta soluciona su error. Saludos ;)

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Comment: Disculpen ya esta más completo :)